# measures context switch with two UNIX pipes running on two processes on a single CPU

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, pipe, context-switch

Quoted from [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces cpu-mechanisms](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf) **Homework (Measurement)** session :

> Measuring the cost of a context switch is a little trickier. The
> lmbench benchmark does so by running two processes on a single CPU,
> and setting up two UNIX pipes between them; a pipe is just one of many
> ways processes in a UNIX system can communicate with one another. The
> first process then issues a write to the first pipe, and waits for a
> read on the second; upon seeing the first process waiting for
> something to read from the second pipe, the OS puts the first process
> in the blocked state, and switches to the other process, which reads
> from the first pipe and then writes to the second. When the second
> process tries to read from the first pipe again, it blocks, and thus
> the back-and-forth cycle of communication continues. By measuring the
> cost of communicating like this repeatedly, lmbench can make a good
> estimate of the cost of a context switch.

My question is , does the pipe itself **must be accessed by 2 different process** ? Or it is just in this case (and also in **lmbench tool**) it was used by different process **in orer to measure context switch** ?
Here are some code I searched on [github](https://github.com/xxyzz/ostep-hw/blob/master/6/1.c):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // measure context switch
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_ZERO(&set);
    CPU_SET(0, &set);

    int first_pipefd[2], second_pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(first_pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pipe(second_pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pid_t cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (cpid == 0) {    // child
        if (sched_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nloops; i++) {
            read(first_pipefd[0], NULL, 0);
            write(second_pipefd[1], NULL, 0);
        }
    } else {           // parent
        if (sched_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nloops; i++) {
            write(first_pipefd[1], NULL, 0);
            read(second_pipefd[0], NULL, 0);
        }
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        printf("context switch: %f microseconds\n", (float) (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec - start.tv_sec * 1000000 - start.tv_usec) / nloops);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> does the pipe itself must be accessed by 2 different process?

Yes, the pipe must be accessed by two processes. Because,

> a context switch is described as the kernel suspending execution of one process on the CPU and resuming execution of some other process that had previously been suspended.

These context switches have a "cost", it takes time to do them.

> Before each tasks runs, CPU needs to know where to load and start the task. This means the system needs to help set up CPU registers and program counters in advance.

In the example code above there is a `fork()` call. This `fork` creates another process, the child, and the parent also resumes execution. See [man 2 fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) The return value of the `fork()` call in the child will be 0 and in the parent it will be the pid of the child.

`sched_setaffinity` is used to ensure that the parent and child both run on the same cpu, `CPU_SET(0, &set);` See [man 2 sched_setaffinity](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) This is done to force context switching. Otherwise in today's multi-processor machines, the parent and child may run on different CPUs.

The block `else if (cpid == 0)` {} will be executed in the child process.
The block `else {}` will be executed in the child process.

parent writes data into `first_pipefd` and gets blocked and suspended, the child resumes execution and read data from `first_pipefd`

Then the child writes data into `second_pipefd` and gets blocked and suspended, the parent resumes execution and read data from `second_pipefd`

The pipe blocking until it is read by the other process is what forces the context switch.

Thus the cpu is switching context between the parent process and the child process `nloops` times.

Comment: what about ignore the 'context switch' thing,  just a pipe . Can I just create a pipe in a single process and read write from it just in that single process ?

Comment: the answer is 'yes' pipe can be accessed by single process . I got the answer from APUE chapter 15.2 pipes.  Quote: "A pipe in a single process is next to useless. Normally, the process that calls pipe then calls fork, creating an IPC channel from the parent to the child, or vice versa."

Comment: Yes, a multi-threaded process can talk to itself using a pipe.

"A pipe in a single process is next to useless." it is like a human taking to themselves. It is called an inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism for that reason.